# Java- Combobox request focus not working

Tags: java, combobox, request, focus

I have got a combobox on which i want to request focus on startup but it wont work. It is the third element in my GUI and i want it to be the focused one on start.
I placed it beneath the adding to the content Pane as i think it is correct but it does nothing.

```
JComboBox comboBox_projekt = new JComboBox();
comboBox_projekt.setName("comboBox_projekt");
comboBox_projekt.setEditable(true);
comboBox_projekt.setBounds(118, 125, 136, 20);
String empty = "";
comboBox_projekt.addItem(empty);

String [ ] AktivProjektJSON = new String[100];  
String [ ] NameProjektJSON = new String[100];   
String [ ] KeyProjektJSON = new String[100];    

JSONObject ProjekteObject = new JSONObject(json_felder.get("projektdaten").toString());
int ProjektJSONlength = ProjekteObject.length() - 1;
for (int key = 0; key<=ProjektJSONlength; key++ ) {
    JSONObject jsonObjectProjekteObjekt = ProjekteObject.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(key));  
    AktivProjektJSON[key] = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt.getString("aktiv");  // String auslesen!!!                         
    NameProjektJSON[key] = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt.getString("projektname");  // String auslesen!!!
    KeyProjektJSON[key] = jsonObjectProjekteObjekt.getString("pk_pr_id");  // String auslesen!!!


     if(AktivProjektJSON[key].equals("1")){
           comboBox_projekt.addItem(NameProjektJSON[key]);
       }
}
//contentPane.add(comboBox_projekt);
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox_projekt);       
comboBox_projekt.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        that.customKeyevent(e);
    }
});

this.contentPane.add(comboBox_projekt);

comboBox_projekt.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            createZusatz(comboBox_projekt, NameProjektJSON, KeyProjektJSON, ProjektJSONlength );
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

comboBox_projekt.requestFocus();
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try to call `requestFocus` once the combobox is visible .

Comment: That helped thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          combo.requestFocus();
       }
    });
```